# Core Bluetooth deprecations for iOS 7

Tags: ios7, core-bluetooth

In iOS 7, some Core Bluetooth things are now deprecated like CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString and CBUUIDDeviceNameString. The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBUUID_Class/Reference/CBUUID.html) state

```
"(Deprecated. There are no replacements for these constants.)"
```

I am wondering what we are supposed to do to replace these GAP things, as the apple docs and examples are of no help. The entire internet also seems to be silent about this. My code is pretty much just like the [Heart Rate Monitor example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Listings/HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m.html) which still has the deprecated code

```
/* GAP (Generic Access Profile) for Device Name */
if ( [aService.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString]] )
{
    [aPeripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:aService];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about you just use the Generic Access service UUID directly?

```
if ( [aService.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1800"]] )//0x1800 is the Generic Access Service Identifier
{
    [aPeripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:aService];
}
```

Check here for details on the [Generic Access Service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.generic_access.xml).

Comment: Well, this does solve the deprecation warnings... but it doesn't really explain why the heck they bothered to deprecate constants if we're supposed to just manually re-make the constants ourselves! I think Apple just hates us

Comment: Also, CBUUIDDeviceNameString can be found here: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicsHome.aspx, it is 0x2A00